# Facetwp include / exclude facet choices

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets, add-filter, facetwp

Okey a quick and simple question :

I installed [facetwp](https://facetwp.com/) I made a facet with the source data properties / [amenities taxonomy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6yX7.png).

there are a hundred choices. in the facet I want to keep 3 choices for example

(Balcony, Alarm, Garden )

in the [documentation](https://facetwp.com/how-to-exclude-certain-categories/) this code should do the trick.. but it does not work.

This is what i put

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_index_row', function( $params, $class ) {
    if ( 'property_amenities' == $params['facet_name'] ) {
        $included_terms = array( 'Balcony', 'Alarm', 'Garden' );
        if ( ! in_array( $params['facet_display_value'], $included_terms ) ) {
            $params['facet_value'] = '';
        }
    }
    return $params;
}, 10, 2 );
```

if anyone has dealt with this problem or know how to solve it please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wondering have you tried the value modifier in each term.
[click to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAhtd.png)

Comment: Oh great !  this is a feature of the new version 3.5.6 
it appeared at the right time. thank you for your answers paul
everything works as expected. no need for codes now .

Comment: So glad all is sorted newneo. I

Answer (score 0):

You didn't place the parameter facet in line two correctly:

```
if ( 'Property Amenities' == $params['property_amenities'] )
```

So first `Property Amenities` is as you first wrote it, then the second `properties_amenities` is as facet reads it, that is where you need to check.
So the first description is your written title and the second is the slug id for the facet to read.

Comment: hi paul thanks for your reply , 
I made the modification, but nothing works, I also tested on the different facet types and other data sources like acf. to be sure that I'm not crazy... 
nothing works the whole code seems wrong? or it's me who didn't understand anything. we really need somebody to test to confirm that the documentation code really works?